# If the discussion has been moved to chat, what am I supposed to do?

Tags: support, status-completed, flagging, flag-reviews

It's the second time that I note the following flag, in the page to review flags.

[image: screenshot]

If the discussion has been moved to chat, what am I supposed to do?
Does the flag means the discussion should be moved to chat, and I have to vote, or take a decision, about that?

Comment: Haha, good question :)

Comment: I've been ignoring these flags, because like you, I can't make heads or tails of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just a "keeping an eye on a new feature" thing during the first couple of days that the automatic comment discussion move (a.k.a. Get-A-Room) existed. This auto-flagging is turned off now, so new flags like that shouldn't pop up.